# Vite middleware or plugin to dynamically rewrite module path resolution?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm building an app that is using Vite API and dev server to view rendered react components in other projects (all on local fs) and their hierarchy.  This is working ok when all the imports are relative paths and we actually want those imports to resolve in the default relative way.

However we actually want relative imports to resolve first relative to our "copy" directory, and then only resolve to the actual relative path as a fallback.  Similar needs for aliases, node_modules, etc.   I'm just starting to work on this but wondering if anyone has a rough sense of how this might be implemented.  I'm guessing this is too messy for normal config so I'm expecting to either write a plugin or middleware that intercepts the paths, does some manual checking, and then rewrites the path as needed, does that sound right?  Or maybe I intercept the file open and return the read in bytes from a location that might change?

Anyone know of a plugin/middleware that does something analogous I can check out?

(Also, while I see middlewares mentioned a lot in Vite docs, I don't see a top level "How to use middlewares" page anywhere)

Comment: [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/aleclarson/vite-tsconfig-paths) might be doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create a vite/rollup plugin to rewrite module resolution paths.  Here is a simple example:

```
function testPlugin(opts = {}): PluginOption[] {
    return [{
        name: 'test-plugin',
        enforce: 'pre',
        resolveId() {
            if (arguments[0].includes('.tsx') && !arguments[0].includes('__inspect')) {
                console.log('--- resolveId', arguments[0])
            }
        },
        load(id) {
            if (id.includes('.tsx') && !id.includes('__inspect')) {
                console.log('--- load', id)
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

In this case you'd want to replace resolveId body with something that munges arguments[0] into the new path you want and return that (instead of undefined in the above example).

The use of enforce: pre is important to make sure other plugins aren't munging these paths before you get access to them.  Similarly when you register these plugins in your vite config, you need to register this plugin first.